# Warm workbox cache NOT on install event?

Tags: angular, workbox

All the workbox warm cache examples i see involve adding a listener for the install event.  This doesn't work well for me, as the urls are dynamic/db driven.  I also might send more/less Urls based on what the browser is being used.

This effort is being done for both performance, and offline tolerance.

Because of this dynamic nature I have implemented a button to elect the user to decide to throw a bunch of urls at the cache.addAll() function, like:

```
caches.open('media-cache').then((cache) => cache.addAll(mediaUrls));
```

**The above does work - but takes up all the browser threads, and nothing works until the cache process completes.**  I haven't been able to determine how-to get this running in the background or w/o taking up all sockets.

Any suggestions/alternatives would be greatly appreciated.